# Can not dependencies MongoDB java driver

Tags: android, mongodb

I'M just start coding , sorry for if I ask a stupid question
I try to use mongodb server to store my app data  , and I follow the installation guide , write this three line in gradle , to use mongodb client yo put and get data from mongodb server

```
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:3.0.4'
compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.4'
compile 'org.mongodb:bson:3.0.4'
```

but it just not work ,can't not build the project ,and  show these message , I try to five hours , google everything , can not find the answer.

> 02-14 16:06:10.323 29072-29173/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting
>   context_name=6 end_time=1455435849923 context_family=1
>   module_id=com.google.android.contextmanager.module.DetectedActivityProducer
>   version=1 sync_state_mod_time_millis=1455437170290
>   start_time=1455435598893 sync_state=0
>   context_id=c5b6400f-b7d9-41f7-8343-cfb9c93dac37 time_type=3
>   proto_blob=[B@3e15cbf1
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint
>   failed: context.context_id (code 2067)
>
> ########################################################### Error Code : 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE) Caused By : Abort due to
>
> constraint violation. (UNIQUE constraint failed: context.context_id
>   (code 2067))
>
> ###########################################################    at
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
>   Method)    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:952)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1609)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1479)
>   at com.google.android.contextmanager.q.ak.a(SourceFile:445)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.q.ak.b(SourceFile:420)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.q.ak.a(SourceFile:370)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.q.ak.b(SourceFile:400)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.q.r.a(SourceFile:381)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.g.a.j.a(SourceFile:58)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.g.a.a.run(SourceFile:52)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.g.i.a(SourceFile:263)    at
>   com.google.android.contextmanager.g.i.handleMessage(SourceFile:254)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)    at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: As a bit of general advice to someone just starting to code and given that you are working with a mobile device application as your target is a general principle that such a mobile client should not attempt to connect to a database server directly. What you really should be looking at is an "intermediate server API" providing something like a RESTful interface ( or some service interface ) that your mobile application talks to instead. So rather that layer is the one that talks to the database and your mobile client talks to the layer instead. The **big** reason for this is security.

Comment: There are **many** other valid reasons why a mobile client should not talk directly to any database. So the general good advice is to stop looking at this particular problem and start working on another layer, or something some other provider can use as an "intermediate" layer instead. Probably a lot to take in if you are new to programming, so maybe even a "lower bar" might be more suited to your first steps.

Comment: thanks ! your advice is really help! 
I think what you say is this right? and web service which allow android device to get data and upload , don't connect the db directly . 
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-your-first-application-mongodb-creating-rest-api-using-mean-stack-part-1

Comment: That's probably the good advice to follow and by all means do try and follow the principles there. If it becomes all to much, then you might want to focus on just one part ( and possibly the mobile app ) at first. Not an endorement, but [parse.com](http://parse.com/) ( which is shutting down, but has released the code for their service ) is one such prebuilt "service" that your mobile app can talk to. It might be worth considering at least as a starting point, and then when you need more you can make your own service. But don't let me stop you having a go at both now if you really want to.